# Разбить (партиционировать) CSV файл по столбцу с датой

Tags: python, csv

Есть файл на 500000 тысяч строк пример:

```
А;B;C
27.06.2020 0:00:00;2157;1,00
27.07.2020 0:00:00;2142;1,00
28.06.2020 0:00:00;2152;1,00
29.06.2020 0:00:00;2142;1,00
01.07.2020 0:00:00;2142;1,00
01.08.2020 0:00:00;2152;1,00
```

Хотелось бы его разбить на под файлы по диапазонам 01.06.2020 до 01.07.2020 включительно и так все периоды. Спасибо.

Comment: Точно включительно? Так то можно было бы отрезать от даты всё кроме месяца и года, сделать из этого новый столбец и `groupby` по нему, а если включать 1-е число следующего месяца в диапазон, то это как-то хитрее будет, придётся цикл делать.

Comment: А в чём сложность-то? Прочитал очередную строку, посмотрел дату, записал в соотв. выходной файл (если под этот диапазон файла нет, то создать-открыть). А если все строки соответствуют шаблон, и не надо заморачиваться на сложный парсинг, то задача чуть ли не тривиальная.

Comment: В том то и сложность что нужно сохранить фомат.

Comment: Дык не надо изменять прочитанные строки, и вся недолга.

Comment: Причем здесь формат? вам говорят о странном промежутке времени. от 1 числа одного месяца до 1 числа следующего ВКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО. Мало того, что алгоритм становится сложнее, так у вас еще и периоды будут пересекаться

Comment: такова задача тут суть в остатках на первое число обработка в 1с проверяет закончилось ли движение по данному id если да то там формируется один документ на конец месяца, а если нет то все продолжается в следующем месяце.

Comment: ну вот в первый файл должны попасть даты с 01.06.2020 до 01.07.2020 __включительно__, а как дальше? С 02.07.20 по какое число и как еще дальше?

Comment: да неверно объяснил , получается с 1 по 1 включительно, а следящий месяц опять с по 1 по 1.

Comment: проверьте кодировку названий столбцов в вашем csv. такое впечатление, что там кириллица.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока, исходя из того, как я понял задачу, и принимая во внимание, что данные по месяцам могут быть неполными, могу предложить попробовать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("part.csv", sep=";", parse_dates=["A"], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(by="A", inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

for i, g in df.groupby(df["A"].dt.month):
    lst = g.index[-1]+1 if g.index[-1] < df.index[-1] else g.index[-1]
    res = df.iloc[g.index[0]:lst+1]
    res.to_csv(f"{i}_part.csv", sep=";", index=None, date_format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

будут созданы файлы "номер_месяца_part.csv". Имейте в виду, что если у вас датасет будет содержать данные за несколько лет, то нужно будет еще в группировку включать год.

В данном случае будет три файла:

6_part.csv:

```
A;B;C
27.06.2020 00:00:00;2157;1,00
28.06.2020 00:00:00;2152;1,00
29.06.2020 00:00:00;2142;1,00
01.07.2020 00:00:00;2142;1,00
```

7_part.csv:

```
A;B;C
01.07.2020 00:00:00;2142;1,00
27.07.2020 00:00:00;2142;1,00
01.08.2020 00:00:00;2152;1,00
```

и 8_part.csv:

```
A;B;C
01.08.2020 00:00:00;2152;1,00
```

Comment: Спасибо ! то что хотел.